# How can I define additional literate replacements without deleting existing ones?

Tags: listings

I'm trying to improve some language definitions that ship with `listings`. Those improvements consists in, among other things, a number of *literate replacements* (see subsection 5.4 of the `listings` manual) used for changing the values of switches and counters that I use to keep track of the context (comment, string, etc.).

The `literate` key (which is used to perform those literate replacements) has the following syntax:

```
literate=[*]⟨replacement item⟩...⟨replacement item⟩
```

where `⟨replacement item⟩` consists in three parts:

```
{⟨stuff to replace⟩}{⟨replacement text⟩}{⟨length⟩}.
```

However, `listings` doesn't seem to offer the possiblity of defining additional literate replacements to those that already exist. As a result, if a user wants to use my language definition but decides to define his/her own literate replacements (using `literate` a second time), all the literate replacements defined as part of my language will be deleted, and my improved syntax highlighting of the language will be broken.

Other keys, such as `keywords`, have a system of *class*, to avoid that type of interference, presumably. Unfortunately, there is no such class system for `literate`. There is also no `moreliterate` key.

How could I allow the user to specify further literate replacements without deleting those already defined?

The code below shows an example of the problem as it stands:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

% ----
% (This language definition would be in some mylang package)
\lstdefinelanguage{mylang}
{%
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    literate={u}{a}1,
}
% -----

% Now, in his/her preamble, the user loads mylang
% but defines new literate replacements, which delete mine
\lstset
{%
    language=mylang,
    literate={(}{[}1 {)}{]}1,
}

\begin{document}

\noindent I would like to get {\ttfamily[papa]} as output, but I get
\begin{lstlisting}
(pupu)
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Related Question: [Multiple literates in a listings style definition](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/202331/multiple-literates-in-a-listings-style-definition).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems that you should be able to smuggle in a new key along the lines of `add to literate`.  I'm not very familiar with the key management system being using in `listings`, so I'll perhaps leave figuring out how to create such a key up to you.

Meanwhile, here is a macro and *key* combo that seem to accomplish what you want.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

%%\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\def\addToLiterate#1{\edef\lst@literate{\unexpanded\expandafter{\lst@literate}\unexpanded{#1}}}
\lst@Key{add to literate}{}{\addToLiterate{#1}}
\makeatother

\lstdefinelanguage{mylang}
{%
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    literate={u}{a}1,
}

\lstset
{%
    language=mylang,
    add to literate={(}{[}1 {)}{]}1,
}

\begin{document}

\noindent I would like to get {\ttfamily[papa]} as output, but I get
\begin{lstlisting}
(pupu)
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Here is the effect:

[image]

Comment: Probably `\protected@edef`, rather than `\edef` or `\expandonce\lst@literate\unexpanded{#1}`

Comment: @egreg Thanks for the suggested improvements.

Comment: I need to allow the user to use the `literate` key directly. Thanks, though; you put me on the right track. I should be able to manage from your answer.

Comment: @Jubobs I'd be interested in seeing where you go from here.  Hope to see an update from you.  :)

Comment: I used your `\addToLiterate` macro to redefine the `literate` key instead of creating a new one: `\lst@Key{literate}{}{\addToLiterate{#1}}`. Thanks again.