# Multiple literates in a listings style definition

Tags: listings

I have a style defined for a language which has lot a lot of `literate` replacements.

In the individual listings that use this style I would like to introduce more listing-specific `literate` replacements. However, it seems that they completely override the ones from the style.

E.g. in the following example I would like both `\` and `>=` to typeset as their math symbol equivalents.

Is it possible to *append to*, not *replace*, a `literate` in a style?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}

\lstdefinestyle{lam}{%
    literate={\\}{$\lambda$}1
}

\begin{lstlisting}[style=lam]
let foo = \x -> x >= 1
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[style=lam, literate={>=}{$\geq$}2]
let bar = \x -> x >= 1
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image: Multiple literates in a listings style definition]

Comment: The question is duplicated. But the answer over there uses eTeX. (not pretty sure) So how should TeX.SX deal with this situation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From `listings.sty`:

> ```
> \def\lst@Literatekey#1\@nil@{\let\lst@ifxliterate\lst@if
>                              \def\lst@literate{#1}}
> \lst@Key{literate}{}{\@ifstar{\lst@true \lst@Literatekey}
>                              {\lst@false\lst@Literatekey}#1\@nil@}
> ```

We could see that `\lst@literate` stores all your replacement items. But every time you say `literate=blahblahblah`, the replacement items is *replaced* but not *appended*. So I would like to try the following trick.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\lstdefinestyle{lam}{%
    literate={\\}{$\lambda$}1}
\begin{lstlisting}[style=lam]
    let foo = \x -> x >= 1
\end{lstlisting}
\begin{lstlisting}[style=lam,literate={>=}{$\geq$}2]
    let bar = \x -> x >= 1
\end{lstlisting}

\makeatletter
\def\lst@Literatekey#1\@nil@{\let\lst@ifxliterate\lst@if
    \expandafter\def\expandafter\lst@literate\expandafter{\lst@literate#1}}
\makeatother
\begin{lstlisting}[style=lam,literate={>=}{$\geq$}2]
    let bar = \x -> x >= 1
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```